# laravel jetstream - redirect user to a specific route after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I use laravel jetstream, and I would like to redirect user to a specific route `/admin/produit` after login.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Fortify is what is used in Jetstream, you can change the default location of redirects after login in your **config/fortify.php**

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the path where users will get redirected during
    | authentication or password reset when the operations are successful
    | and the user is authenticated. You are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
```

Alternatively you can set this during runtime with **Config::set("fortify.home").**

Furthermore if you need really complex behavior you can change entire Fortify Reponse class:

https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects

Answer (score 0):

change this line in RouteServiceProvider.php

public const HOME = '/';

to

public const HOME = '/admin/produit';

Comment: Ok , i try this..the problem is that the page "/admin/produit" is displayed on a popup, there is no redirection